# Корень слова «Заседание» и связь со словом «Сидеть»

Tags: этимология

Никак не могу разобраться от какого слова происходит «Заседание». Еще есть «Председатель», у которого тот же корень. Вроде бы само мероприятие подразумевает что некоторый круг лиц будет что-то обсуждать, и скорее всего сидя, так как обсуждение обычно идет продолжительное время. Чувствуется некоторая связь с английским словом "Chairman" в плане логики происхождения. Но мне не понятно почему в таком случае вместо корня «Сид» от слова «Сидеть» используется неизвестно откуда взявшийся «Сед». Не разъясните его происхождения?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Заседание" и "председатель" — это кальки с "sessio" и "praesidens".

Что касается корня, это -сид- "неизвестно откуда взявшийся", исходная форма корня как раз -сед- (точнее, -сѣд-). Про "неизвестно откуда" читаем у Фасмера: [Вост.-слав. *сидѣти из *sěděti, где i получено в результате ассимиляции во 2 л. ед. sědiši, 3 л. ед. sěditь и т. д.](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-11954.htm) Поэтому логично, что "е" сохраняется в глаголах первого спряжения, где никакое [i] не влияет: "заседать", "приседать", "наседать" и т.д., точно так же, как "сосед", "седло" и "село", где ровно тот же корень (в случае "села" — исторически). Так что тут даже индоевропейский аблаут ни при чем. (А "при чем" он, например, в корне -сад- — "садиться", "осадок", ну и собственно "сад"; это праиндоевропейская o-ступень *sod-.)

Comment: To be precise - сад<*so:d, with long o (it is another part of ablaut, which is 0/o/o:/e/e:)